# Difference in protection between GFCI breaker vs receptacle?

Tags: electrical, gfci

I am selling my house in Illinois, and the buyer's home inspector complained that the house needed to have GFCI receptacles instead of GFCI breakers for the bathroom and kitchen.  I am under the belief that they provide the same protection.  Am I mistaken?  Is there a safety issue, or is this just busy work?

Comment: Did the inspector give a reason? My previous house had GFCI breakers in the main panel outside on the garage -- it only took one GFCI trip on a cold 0 degree morning to convince me that I'd rather have GFCI receptacles so I don't need to go out into the cold and snow to reset the breaker.

Comment: Ask the inspector to show you the codez, or some other official requirement. If it's simply a request from the buyer, it may be negotiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code states "GFCI protected" is required in bathrooms, the location of the device is not specified. NEC 2014, 210.8.A1.
The device can be in the breaker panel this is considered a readily accessible location by code. Some home inspectors think readily accessible means in the bathroom. The breaker panel is by definition a readily accessible location.

Answer (score 2):

GFCI breakers provide better protection.  GFCI outlets have unprotected exposed conductors behind the faceplate, they are going into the terminals called "line".

The inspector may be concerned with ease of inspection, i.e. quickly determining that the kitchen has the required equipment.  GFCI outlets make that easy.

Speaking or that, there are labeling requirements which also make that easy.  If it isn't perfectly obvious by the "test" and "reset" buttons, any GFCI protected outlet must have a label saying "GFCI protected". He would be correct to flunk you on that.

Comment: Does it have to be a label, or could I just write with a Sharpie on the cover plate?

Comment: Only if you do lettering for a living lol.  There's actually a rule that requires work be neat and "workmanlike", NEC 112 I think.   I would find a friend with a Dymo style labelmaker.  Cut the excess margins off so it looks neat.

Comment: This must be your opinion as older GFCI breakers are no better than GFCI outlets. The main advantage to GFCI outlets is that they can be reset at the point of use and home owners and renters  are less likely to remove them. I have replaced many breakers with outlets for home owners.

Comment: @EdBeal He explicitly gives a reason as to why breakers may be better than receptacles; receptacles have unprotected conductors/terminals behind them. If you somehow managed to spill water so that it went into the box, the GFCI could not cut power to these.

Comment: Not a true concern. If it was ALL OUTLETS WOULD BE A PROBLEM.!!! Every connection in a box or panel has stripped wires to make the connection. There are Strip gauges on the back of the outlet. If properly stripped there is absolutely no exposed wire.